# Shell script to find .git folder and then run git branch command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have multiple git repositories cloned, i want to `cd` to these repostories and then run `git branch` command in all these repositories.

Can any one suggest how can i achieve using shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all git repo dirs:

```
 find "YOUR_BASE_DIR" -type d -name '.git'|sed 's#/\.git$##'
```

Run git command on a given path instead of the current one:

```
git -C A_REPO_PATH branch(/pull/show.....)
```

You can combine the two commands together to achieve your goal.

#### take this please.

```
 find "YOUR_BASE_DIR" -type d -name '.git'|sed 's#/\.git$##'|xargs -I {} git -C {} branch
```

Comment: There are many ways @Kiran, loop, build the command str and pipe to sh `|sh` .. using variables, xargs... you'll find it.

Comment: above command is not working. i have multiple repositories, i want to run ```git branch``` command in all the repositories.

Comment: @Kiran of course it won't work if you just copy & paste, you need to feed the `A_REPO_PATH` placeholder with the result of the 1st command. as I said, combine them.

Comment: @Kiran add an example cmd, you can copy, but you have to change the base dir.

Comment: do you know to do the same thing using Groovy?

Comment: also i like to know for executing ``` find "YOUR_BASE_DIR" -type d -name '.git'|sed 's#/\.git$##'|xargs -I {} git -C {} branch```  for each repository i would also want to save ```echo "$branchname" >> file.txt```  branch name in a variable present in file.txt